# Homebridge how to call service function in function?

Tags: node.js

Homebridge trigger function in other function

I want to trigger a binded function such as getCurrentFanSpeed in setInterval

I have tried .getCurrentFanSpeed or .getCurrentFanSpeed.call();

```
setInterval(function () {
    fanservice.getCurrentFanSpeed ;
    fanservice.log("Interval: Get Current Fan Speed");
}, this.interval);
```

Actually it doesn't run the code.
only displayed  Interval: Get Current Fan Speed every 10sec

Comment: You didn't try `fanservice.getCurrentFanSpeed()`

Comment: thx,because homebridge has a default callback, i need the callback to run the homebridge default function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that i can just use emit() to call the function

such as

```
fanService.getCharacteristic(Characteristic.RotationSpeed).emit("set");
```

thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

If Fanservice accepts callback function, You can get a result like below.

```
       setInterval(async function () {
              fanservice.getCurrentFanSpeed(function(result) => {
                  console.log(result);
              });
             fanservice.log("Interval: Get Current Fan Speed");
        }, this.interval);
```

It might help you

Comment: Hi .i watch the log it returned getCurrentFanSpeed is not a function.because homebridge has a default callback, i need the callback to run the homebridge default function

Comment: So, `fanservice` is an object?

Comment: yup fanservice is an object

Comment: Quit confusion. Do you want to execute a script without calling the function? It must be a simple callback function.

Comment: Umm i think this is bez of the homebridge default setting

Comment: As I know, This impossible to execute code like this.

Comment: Thank very much i found the method and i will past at the below